# I want to replace content inside a String which starts with # if it starts with !# it must skip it

Tags: java, regex, str-replace

As the title suggest i only want to replace content which starts **#** and skip content which starts with **!** Here is the code snippet. it is not skipping the word which starts with **!#**

```
String test = "Hello #Admin  Welcome this is Your welcome page !#Admin  This is #Admin"
```

NOTE:- It must skip !#Admin when replacing.

```
String out = test.replaceAll("#Admin", "MyAdministrator");
log.debug("OutPut: "+out);

OutPut: Hello MyAdministrator  Welcome this is Your welcome page !MyAdministrator  This is MyAdministrator
```

**How can i Ignore the word which starts with Exclamation mark.**

THANKS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind?

```
String test = "Hello #Admin  Welcome this is Your welcome page !#Admin  This is #Admin";
String out = test.replaceAll("(?<!!)#Admin", "MyAdministrator");
System.out.println("OutPut: "+out);
```

The lookbehind is `(?<!!)`.

Comment: @jlordo Yea, it was really close!

Comment: @Jerry I wanted to ask one more thing is that what if i have HashMap containing regexpression and values to replace in this Instance it does not work  String out = test.replaceAll("(?<!!)"entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());?

Comment: @mgk22 Can you extract the values you need from the HashMap and convert them into string which you can then use for the replaceAll? I'm not familiar with HashMaps unfortunately :(

Comment: @Jerry i tried doing this using StringBuilder and then getting value from toString() method it does not replace it at all, by the way thanks for your reply and time

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    String out = test.replaceAll("(?<!!)#Admin", "MyAdministrator");
```

this is called negative lookbehind, see Pattern API

Comment: I wanted to ask one more thing is that what if i have HashMap containing regexpression and values to replace in this Instance it does not work  String out = test.replaceAll("(?<!!)"entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());?